# Select input not grouping to other inputs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically the issue I'm experiencing is that I'm trying to group all three of these inputs so that it is one long connected form. However the problem I'm experiencing is that the select input is not joining to the rest of the form correctly is there something that I'm doing incorrect.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <div class="input-group">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                          <option>1</option>
                          <option>2</option>
                          <option>3</option>
                          <option>4</option>
                  </select>
              </div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true">
        </span></span>  

        </div>
```

So the issue I'm having is related to the `<select>` and essentially what I'm trying to achieve is for the above form to look similar to this; with the first greyed out area to be the select and the second greyed out area to be the search icon.

[image]

Comment: Post a minimal working code snippet so we can see what you mean

Comment: @LGSon Thank you for the suggest will post that shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the `dropdown-menu` component

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Select <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true">
        </span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great response thankyou really appreciate your time, however I need to use `select` as the options will have values, so when the form is submitted the value of the select is posted so I'm unsure if I'd be able to use this. +1 though for providing and alternative solution.

Comment: I think Bootstrap don't have `<select>` as an option because it is not easy to style and have lots of cross-browsers different appearance.

Comment: Okay thank-you really appreciate it, Will mark this as the answer if I don't see any alternative solutions posted within the next 10 minutes thankyou though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [bootstrap-select library](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) that convert `<select>` into bootstrap-like dropdowns.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <select class="selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```